# jQuery selector error: unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this selector:

```
$('.kleo-main-header .nav > li a[href=#undefined]')
```

And I get an error in chrome's console:

```
 Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .kleo-main-header .nav > li a[href=#undefined]
```

I tried with double quotes instead of single quotes but it didn't change. Any idea on what's causing this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to quote the attributes value when it contains special characters that are otherwise used in a selector, like the hash, which is also used for ID's.

jQuery uses a regex that searches for periods, hashes and such things in selectors, to figure out if it should search for an ID, class, or whatever.

```
$('.kleo-main-header .nav > li a[href="#undefined"]')
```

Note that you're matching an element that looks like `<a href="#undefined">anchor</a>` ?

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4dewbdmm/)